# TypeError: setEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am having problem on my reactjs. I can't open login.
setEmail is not function and for setPassword is same. I tried to edit and checked my codes but still and error. what should I do?
I am already run it. but when I create my username there is an error.
[here the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFgTb.png)

```
here the codes for Login.js


import React from 'react';

const login = (props) => {

    const { email, setEmail, password, setPassword, handleLogin, handleSignup, hasAccount, setHasAccount, emailError, passwordError} = props;
    
    return (
        <section className="login">
            <div className="loginContainer">
                <label htmlFor="">Username</label>
                <input type="text" 
                    autoFocus 
                    required 
                    value={email} 
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                />
                <p className="errorMsg">{ emailError }</p>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input 
                    type="password"
                    requited
                    value={password}
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
```

here for App.js
App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// import Login from '../Login';
import routes from "./routes";
import withTracker from "./withTracker";


import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";

import './App.css';
import fireDb from './firebase/firebase';
import './App.css';
//Components
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";
import Login from "./views/Login";



function App() {

  //States
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState('');
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setEmail('')
    setPassword('')
  }

  const clearErrors = () => {
    setEmailError('')
    setPasswordError('')
  }

  //Login function
  const handleLogin = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fireDb.auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(error => {
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
        case 'auth/user-disabled':
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          setEmailError(error.message);
          break;
        case 'auth/wrong-password':
          setPasswordError(error.message);
          break;
      }
    })
  }

  //Signup function
  const handleSignup = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fireDb.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(error => {
        switch (error.code) {
          case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
          case 'auth/invalid-email':
            setEmailError(error.message);
            break;
          case 'auth/weak-password':
            setPasswordError(error.message);
            break;
        }
      })
  }

  //Function for logout
  const handleLogout = () => {
    fireDb.auth().signOut();
  }

  //Authentication listener
  const authListener = () => {
    fireDb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if ( user ){
        clearInputs();
        setUser(user);
      } else { setUser('') }
    })
  }

  //React listener.
  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { user ? (
        <Dashboard handleLogout={handleLogout} />
      ) : (
          <Login
            email={email}
            setEmail={setEmail}
            password={password}
            setPassword={setPassword}
            handleLogin={handleLogin}
            handleSignup={handleSignup}
            hasAccount={hasAccount}
            setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
            emailError={emailError}
            passwordError={passwordError}
          />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


export default () => (
  <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
    <div>
{/*       
      <Dashboard/> */}
      {routes.map((route, index) => {
        return (
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={withTracker(props => {
              return (
                <route.layout {...props}>
                  <route.component {...props} />
                </route.layout>
              );
            })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </Router>
);




// export default App;
```

[the errors can not setEmail][2]

Comment: where are you making the setEmail function? You are defining it as `useState("")`

Comment: can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `setEmail`, so you'll need to provide a simple reproducible example.

Comment: I m already uploaded in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-surf-60sin

Comment: @Saddy I can changed it, but it doesnt works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because your login component is loading directly without any props. You should load the `login` component through the `App` component to get all the props.

For that make the below changes in routes.js,

```
{
    path: "/login",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: App // export App and import here
  },
```

Working Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-fog-efen8?file=/src/App.js